# Proving a specific recurrence relation theorem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

I'm trying to come up with a proof for this theorem:

Let $c_1$ and $c_2$ be real numbers with $c_2 != 0$.  Suppose that $r^2 - c_1 r - c_2 = 0$ has only one root, $r_0$.  A sequence $\{a_n\}$ is a solution of the recurrence relation $a_n = c_1 a_{n-1} + c_2 a_{n-2}$.  If and only if $a_n$ = $a_1r^n_0$ + $a_2nr^n_0$, for $n = 0,1,2...$ where $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ are constants.

(I'm trying to also make the $a_n$ sequence above have the subscript of n-1 and n-2, respectively, not subtracted from the whole equation, if someone can tell me how to edit that!)  Thank you!

**My answer so far..not sure if this is right**

Proof: Suppose $a_n$ = $a_1r_0^n$ + $a_2r_0^n$.  By definition, $r_0$ is the only root of $r^2 - c_1 r - c_2$, so $r_0^2 = c_1 r_0 + c_2$.  Moreover, since it's the only root, it's also a root of the derivative, so $2r_0 = c_1$.  Then:

$$c_1a_{n-1} + c_2a_{n-2} = c_1[\alpha_1r_0^{n-1} + \alpha_2(n-1)r_0^{n-1}] + c_2[\alpha_1 r_0^{n-2} + \alpha_2 (n-2)r_0^{n-2}]$$
$$...$$
$$=\alpha_1r_0^n + \alpha_2nr_0^n + \alpha_2r_0^{n-1} [c_1 - 2r_0]$$
$$ = a_n$$

So,  $a_n$ satisfies the recurrence relation.  If $a_0$ = $C_0$ and $a_1 = C_1$, then $\alpha_1 = C_0$ and $C_1 = (\alpha_1 + \alpha_2)r_0$, so $\alpha_2 = \frac{C_1 - C_0r_0}{r_0}$

Since this is a unique solution, we are done.

Comment: How can a quadratic equation have only one root?

Comment: @RonGordon: $x^2+2x+1$ has only one root.

Comment: We call that a double root and it is treated accordingly - there are two independent solutions to an equation with that characteristic equation.

Comment: @jtm22: There's a flaw in your theorem. The general solution to a second-order recurrence relation with a single root is of the form $a_n = (\alpha_1+n\alpha_2)r^n$. The extra "$n$" is important.

Comment: @RonGordon: Actually, we call it a repeated root, not a double root. It's one root with multiplicity 2. It is entirely acceptable to refer to it as a single root.

Comment: Potato, potahto.  The point is, it is a fallacy to say that a quadratic has only one root.  Better to say that you are looking for a double, repeated,..., whatever, root.

Comment: @Glen O where is the flaw in the original equation?  Maybe I transcribed it wrong from my sheet...

Comment: @GlenO http://gyazo.com/7df0d072aaefed04e2935a834121c467

Comment: @jtm22: if you look on the third row, it says: "...if and only if $a_n = \alpha_1 r_0^n+\alpha_2nr_0^n$, for...". The "n" after the $\alpha_2$ is what you missed... although you may have only missed it in the part where you transcribed the question. The formatting issues prevented me from seeing the $n$ showing up elsewhere in your question.

Comment: I've just submitted an edit to clean up the formatting and fix the missing $n$. Let me know if there's an error (other than the fact that I forgot to fix the $\alpha$ subscripts to match).

Comment: @GlenO so does that mean that you agree that the original (non-transcribed) version is correct?  (thanks, btw for editing!)

Comment: It mostly looks right. Is there a reason to think it isn't?

Comment: @GlenO - I noticed (what i thought) was an error in the explanation..specifically since there is no explanation of a formula for a_n, which I thought was needed to be fully correct.  But if you don't see any errors, I must be overthinking it.  Would you be free for a second to take a look at one other problem I had?  I don't think they like continued discussion here, but would you be open to chatting on GChat or E-mail for a minute or two?  Thanks, Glen!

Comment: OK, there was an error, now that I looked again - in the proof, the last bit says "then $\alpha_1=C_0$ and $C_1=(\alpha_0+\alpha_1)r_0$, so $\alpha_1=\frac{C_1-C_0r_0}{r_0}$."... the problem being, it switches from using $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ to using $\alpha_0$ and $\alpha_1$ part way through. I've corrected it in my second edit to your question.

Comment: @GlenO That makes sense..Thanks for correcting it.  I'm still stuck one one more little problem..it will only take a second, if you have a minute to look at it.  Would you be able to contact me through GMail if you aren't too busy?  Thanks Glen! (goonthegnome@gmail.com)